# How to retrieve Dynamics 365 Purchase Order information via Postman

Tags: rest, get, postman, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm new to D365 FO and am trying to retrieve Purchase Order Header and Line info via Postman.

I have logged into D365 and created a connection in Postman, but what is the URI to actually retrieve the info?

Also, is there a list of common URI - sales order, purchase order, product etc?

So far I have tried the below to no avail:

{{resource}}/data/PurchaseOrderHeaders?$filter=PurchaseOrderNumber eq '12345'

{{resource}}/api/data/v9.0/purchaseorders(12345)

{{resource}}/api/data/purchaseorders(12345)

{{resource}}/data/PurchTable/PurchaseOrders('12345')

Comment: Have you registered the application in AAD first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URI format for accessing via oData is {d365BaseURI}/data/{EntityPublicCollectionName}

Options for getting the list of entity endpoints:

1. You can get a list of entities from {d365BaseURI}/Metadata/DataEntities
2. You can download the list of data entities from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/s-e/global/axtechrefrep_61) and the "PublicCollectionName" column in the DataEntities csv file is what you should use.  This list does not look like is has been updated since 10.0.17 so may not have the most up to date info.
3. From within a D365 development VM, open Visual Studio, and search through the Data Entities in Application Explorer. The PublicCollectionName property of the entity is what should be used.
4. You can get the list of entities from the (very large) metadata file located here: {d365BaseURI}/data/$metadata

Entities you requested:

- Sales order headers: SalesOrderHeadersV2
- Sales order lines: CDSSalesOrderLinesV2 or SalesOrderLines
- PO Headers: PurchaseOrderHeadersV2
- PO lines: PurchaseOrderLinesV2
- Products: ReleasedProductsV2 or ProductsV2

So for Purchase Order Headers, you could use something like this: {d365BaseURI}/data/PurchaseOrderHeadersV2?$filter=PurchaseOrderNumber eq 'your-PO-Number'

If you aren't sure what the field is named that you want to filter on, use the `?$top=10` filter to just return the first 10 results which you can inspect. For example: {d365BaseURI}/data/PurchaseOrderHeadersV2?$top=10

Here are the steps for setting up PostMan, which include creating a request to get the auth token, storing the auth token in a PostMan environment variable, and using the token in your D365 requests.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test

Comment: Thank you for the above, as a newbie to D365 the above is a massive help - thanks again.

Comment: @LordMichael no problem.  One other thing to mention is D365 uses oData v4 so here are few more helpful links. Not all oData standards are implemented by D365 so the 2nd link has some info about what is: https://www.odata.org/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata