# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations API call to update product record

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'd like to make an API request (via HTTP?) from another server to update a product record inside Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations, but so far I haven't even been able to find API documentation.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm working in PHP, but I can make use of code from other languages.  Or even just a link to documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for individual entities in D365 is not very good, and only a few are documented.

D365 uses the oData version 4.0 standard, so you can get a lot of info regarding how to interact from here: https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Products and Released Products entity are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-entities#built-in-entities

D365 OData API info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata

Authentication overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/services-home-page

You use different HTTP methods for different operations, i.e. read data = GET, create = POST, update = PATCH, delete = DELETE.

Also see my answer here for how to get the list of entities in D365: [How to retrieve Dynamics 365 Purchase Order information via Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203052/how-to-retrieve-dynamics-365-purchase-order-information-via-postman/77326490#77326490)